# SQL Plus Report Column formatting (PL SQL ?)

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am trying to achieve these results :

[image]

With the following code, the formatting is confusing. This all relates to one table within the DB "Consultant" (see end of post for table):

```
Set echo off
Remark  *** Set up the SQL*Plus environment ***

Set Pagesize 24
Set Feedback Off

Remark  *** Format the Columns ***
Column  ctype   Format A5       Heading Car|Type
Column  grade   Format A5       Heading Grade
Column  A       Format A3       Heading A
Column  B       Format A3       Heading B
Column  C       Format A3       Heading C
Column  D       Format A3       Heading D
Column  E       Format A3       Heading E
Column  F       Format A3       Heading F
Column  G       Format A3       Heading G



Remark  *** The Query ***

SELECT      c_type# as ctype,
        TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'A'))   as A, 
        TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'B'))   as B,
        TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'C')) as C,
        TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'D')) as D,
        TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'E')) as E,
        TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'F')) as F,
        TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'G')) as G
FROM        consultant
GROUP BY    c_type#
ORDER BY    ctype
/
Remark  *** Reset the environment ***
Clear columns
Ttitle Off
Btitle Off
Set Feedback on
Set Pagesize 20 
Set Echo on
```

So far I am getting this result :

[image]

```
create table CONSULTANT (
Consultant_Id   char(7)
            constraint pk_consultant_Consultant_Id primary key
            constraint cc_consultant_Consultant_Id check
                        ((substr(Consultant_Id,1,1) between 'A' and 'Z')
                        and
                        (substr(Consultant_Id,2,1) between '0' and '9')
                    and
                        (substr(Consultant_Id,3,1) between '0' and '9')
                        and  
                        (substr(Consultant_Id,4,1) between '0' and '9')
                        and  
                        (substr(Consultant_Id,5,1) between '0' and '9')
                        and  
                        (substr(Consultant_Id,6,1) between '0' and '9')
                        and  
                        (substr(Consultant_Id,7,1) between '0' and '9')),
Name            varchar2(28)            
            constraint cc_consultant_Name check (Name = upper (Name))
            constraint nn_consultant_Name not null,
Address     varchar2(80) 
            constraint cc_consultant_Address check (Address = upper     (Address))
            constraint nn_consultant_Address not null,
DOB         date
            constraint nn_consultant_DOB not null,
Grade           char(1)
            constraint nn_consultant_Grade not null
            constraint fk_consultant_Grade references GRADE(Grade), 
C_Type#     char(3)
            default 'GF8'
            constraint fk_consultant_C_Type# references         CAR_TYPE(C_Type#),
Mileage_Allow   number(3,2)
            default null
            constraint cc_consultant_Mileage_Allow check     (Mileage_Allow between 0 and 0.67),
constraint cc_consultant_C_Type#_Mlg_Allw check
((C_Type# is null and Mileage_Allow is not null)
or
(C_Type# is not null and Mileage_Allow is null))
)
/
```

Comment: where is the question?